# Unable to fetch data in angular application using ipad mini

Tags: angularjs, express

I am making an angular application for Dashboard. I am making several http requests from my controllers. When i build this project using grunt, it runs well on my machine and fetches the data from the express server which is also running on localhost on port 1222. But when i run the built code on ipad, the app is unable to fetch data. I am totally lost about what could be the possible reason for this.

My express server code is written below:

```
    var express = require("express");
    var contacts = require("./db_interactions");
    var app = express();
    app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    });

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {

     // Website you wish to allow to connect
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin || '*');
     // Request methods you wish to allow
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
     // Request headers you wish to allow
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

     // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
     // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

     // Pass to next layer of middleware
     if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
          res.send(200);
      } else {
         next();
      }
     });

     app.get("/:appName/users", contacts.index);
     app.get('/:appName/signup', contacts.signup);
     app.get('/:appName/overall/session', contacts.session);
     app.get('/:appName/activity/:span', contacts.overallActivity);
     app.get('/:appName/releases', contacts.releases);
     app.get('/:appName/individual/session/:username', contacts.individualSession);
     app.get('/:appName/recentactivity', contacts.recentActivity);
     app.post('/:appName/addreleases', contacts.addReleases);
     app.delete('/:appName/deletereleases/:id', contacts.deleteReleases);
     app.listen(1222, "127.0.0.1");
```

The structure of a sample http request from my angular directive is as follows :

```
      $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'http://127.0.0.1:1222/' + 'mukund' + '/individual/session/' + user
        }).success(function(data) {

        }).
        error(function() {});
```

I have console logged the data on every function in server side but it is not printing anything. I think that the request is not reaching the server. Can anyone figure out the reason why the request is not reaching to the server when it is made by an ipad but works fine on my local system.
                         Thank you in advance....

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use localhost on iOS devices. You need to use a webserver.

Comment: @FedericoGiust actually i am not exactly using localhost as ip.This is   192.168.0.115 Even after this if i could not connect to the server. Can you suggest me a way to connect it..

Comment: Ip Addresses starting 192.168 and 10.0 are usually private (local network) addresses which are probably blocked as well as localhost. Is that the ip of your ipad or your server on your network? If that's the ip on your network, I would try hosting that on the web and use a domain instead.

Comment: @FedericoGiust yeah you were right. I managed to solved the problem. Actually my server was binded to serve on 127.0.0.1 only i changed it to 0.0.0.0 and it works. Thank you very much. If you post this as an answer, i will accept it. Thank you once again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't use localhosy on iOS devices you need to use a webserver.

Ip Addresses starting 192.168 and 10.0 are usually private (local network) addresses which are probably blocked as well as localhost.

Is that the ip of your ipad or your server on your network?

If that's the ip on your network, I would try hosting that on the web and use a domain instead.